# Copy files into folder in S3 ends up at parent folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

If I give this s3 copy command and `myfiles` is a folder with subfolders and files in it:

```
aws s3 cp myfiles s3://ansible.preprod-us-east/R2.4.3/ --recursive
```

It copies the contents of the `myfiles` folder (including all subfolders and files) to the R2.4.3 folder. How can I copy the myfiles directory to the `R2.4.3/myfiles` directory?

Comment: I would try adding a trailing `/` to `myfiles`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the prefix in the destination,

```
aws s3 cp myfiles s3://ansible.preprod-us-east/R2.4.3/myfiles/ --recursive
```